# contact sensor compiling error related to the body forces/torques after installing updates

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I updated ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and I am running Gazebo standslone 1.8.6 and Ros fuerte.
The problem is after installing updates the contact sensor  plugin compiling error

error: ‘const class gazebo::msgs::JointWrench’ has no member named ‘body_2_torque’

before the updates the plugin was running perfectly. And this error only related to body forces and torques

```
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < contacts.contact(i).wrench_size(); ++j)      
    {                

      std::cout << j << " wrench between [" <<                              
        contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_name() << "] and [" <<         
        contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_name() << "]\n";               
      std::cout << "  body_1_force: "                                       
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_force().x() << " "  
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_force().y() << " "  
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_force().z() << "\n";                                                                               
      std::cout << "  body_2_force: "                                       
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_force().x() << " "  
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_force().y() << " "  
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_force().z() << "\n";                                                                               
      std::cout << "  body_1_torque: "                                      
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_torque().x() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_torque().y() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_torque().z() << "\n";                                                                              
      std::cout << "  body_2_torque: "                                      
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_torque().x() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_torque().y() << " "
                << contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_2_torque().z() << "\n";                                                                              
    }
```

otherwise the position , depth, normal and collision strings are working.
Any suggestions are so much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3903/contact-sensor-compiling-error-related-to-the-body-forces/torques-after-installing-updates./) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The gazebo::msgs::JointWrench has changed.

For force:

```
contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_wrench().force()
```

and for torque:

```
contacts.contact(i).wrench(j).body_1_wrench().torque()
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-07-29**:
Thanks a lot. it works!